# Find file in a directory with python and if multiple files show up matching decide which to open

Tags: python, file

basically what the title says, what is the best approach to do this?

I was looking at a few tools like the os.walk and scandir but then I am not sure how I would store them and decide which file to open if they are multiples. I was thinking I would need to store in a dictionary and then decide which numbered item  I want.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to answer. If you can show us the code you've tried so far and explain why it's not working we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`list_of_files = os.listdit(some_directory)`

which returns a list of names of the files that exist in that directory, you can easily add some of these names to a dictionary based on their index in this list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that implements the specifications you have outlined.  It may require some tinkering as your specs evolve, but it's an ok start.  See the docs for the `os` builtin package for more info :)

```py
import os

def my_files_dict(directory, filename):
    myfilesdict = []
    with os.scandir(directory) as myfiles:
        for f in myfiles:
            if f.name == filename and f.is_file:
                myfilesdict.append(f.name)
    return dict(enumerate(myfilesdict))
```